# Spring call method from inside of a method without affecting the calling method

Tags: spring

Can someone please help .

The scenario is that  i want to call a new method from inside of other method calls without affecting the processing happening in methods a(),b(),c()

Also, any exception in  method newClass.d(id) should not affect processing in a(),b(), c()
ideally would like to call newClass.d(id) after method a() has completed its processing

```
method a()
{
  //calls
   method b()
}

@transnational
method b()
{
  //calls method c
  method c()
}

method c()
{
    //this stores some value into database and gets an id
    //I need this id and want to call another method d(pass ID)
    // i want to call it in a way that if there is any exception in method d(pass ID), its should not affect a(),b(),c()

}

class newClass
{
  method d(id)
  {
    //does something
  }

}
```

Is there any better way of doing this in Spring.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If `NewClass` is a service/component, and you call it within methodC like 
`newClassInstance.methodD()`

Then i would suggest adding an annotation on `methodD`

`@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)`

Doing so, spring will start a new transaction for methodD execution, and if this one fail, it will rollback only changes made in methodD

But, if an exception is thrown from methodD without being catched, it will rollback also previous transaction

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I am also looking at if i can use event listeners  https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2